# Prevent the page to load elements in the page refresh ASP?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reload

I have a page that add Items to RadioButtonList with this code :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
RD.Read()
    RBQ1.Items.Add(RD.GetString(3))
    RBQ1.Items.Add(RD.GetString(4))
    RBQ1.Items.Add(RD.GetString(5))
    RBQ1.Items.Add(RD.GetString(6))
End Sub
```

When I click in any button in the same page, the entire page `reload` and it display 8 items in the RadioButtonList, If I click for the second time I get 12 items in the RBL...

How can I `prevent` the page to reload if I click in this button. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only add the items to the control if IsPostBack is false.

```
If not IsPostBack then
    RD.Read()
    RBQ1.Items.Add(RD.GetString(3))
    ...
End If
```

As far as not having the page reload - generally when a button is clicked you do want to submit a postback to the server so you can perform whatever action the user initiates with the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to populate the RadioButtonList the first time the page loads, you need to wrap that code in

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   // this is the first time the page loads > populate your RadioButtonList here
Else
   // this is when the page reloads after postback
End If
```